# Can the system $x+y=3$, $2x^2 + y^2 = 5$ be solved using matrices?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, inverse, quadratics, matrix-equations

$$ x+y=3 $$

$$ 2x^2 + y^2 = 5 $$

I solved it by substituting

$x = 3- y $

$2(3-y)^2 + y^2 =5 $

therefore, $ y= 2+\frac{i}{\sqrt3} $, $y= 2-\frac{i}{\sqrt3}$

However, I want to know that can I solve it by using the matrix inversion ?

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix inversion"? Matrices are normally used to solve linear systems, but yours is nonlinear.

Comment: by using ax=b ,,, but the problems is there's a difference between $x^2$ and just single X

Comment: Matrices can be applied for equations with same degrees.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is **NO** as this system is not a linear one. However, if you try to solve this system graphically, you can see that the ellipse $2x^2$+$y^2$=$5$ lies completely inside the line $x+y$=$3$. They never intersect each other thereby suggesting no solution in Real plane.

Comment: then how can i do? however, my answers are correct?